# Android Widget Change Height To Be Smaller

Tags: android, android-widget

For my widget, I am trying to make the widget thinner in height.
Even if I change minHeight to 20dp, it stays the same on the phone.

I want it to be like the OneNote application widget that has a small height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget1">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you set the minimum height of the widget (the number of Rows / Column that your widget will use).
You can define the "apparent" height of your widget on the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget_mosaic_row_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:background="BLACK"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

For exemple, this will result as a black horizontal linearlayout with an height of 20dip.

I hope this will help you ^^

Comment: .... I honestly didn't see that this question was asked in January.
Shame on me. Maybe he's still on this problem ? =P